# Torsion in the Betti cohomology of complex surfaces

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Q1. So what is the "simplest example" of a compact complex manifold of dimenension $2$, say  $X$, for which $H_B^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ has non-trivial torsion.

Q2. How do we think about these torsion elements? What is the geometrical content behind it?

Comment: An Enriques surface. Torsion in $H^2$ equals torsion in $H_1$ which
comes from etale covers with abelian Galois group.

Comment: Thnaks Donu. But I guess that in general there is no reason why the torsion in $H^1$ should inject in $H^2$. May be I should also require
$X$ to be simply connected. In any case, thanks for your example. 

Comment: Hugo, I realize I was bit too concise (but I'm a bit rushed).
The identification with $H^2(X,\Z)_{torsion}\cong H_1(X,\Z)_{torsion}$
comes from he universal coefficient theorem. So for simply connected
surfaces, there is no torsion. One can also see that $Pic$ surjects
onto the torsion in $H^2$, and then take the Kummer cover associated
to the corresponding line bundle.

Comment: Another nice example is the Godeaux surface. See book by Barth,
Peters and Van de Venn.

Comment: Donu is saying that the torsion in $H^2$ is isomorphic to the torsion in $H_1$. More precisely, by universal coefficients the torsion in $H^2$ is isomorphic to the torsion in $Ext(H_1,\mathbb Z)$, which if $H_1$ is finitely generated is $Hom((H_1)_{tors},\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ and isomorphic to $(H_1)_{tors}$. If $X$ is simply connected then $H^2$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Yes, I just worked it out for myself. I had forgotten about the universal coefficient theorem for chain complexes. I also just amused myself to construct explicitly all the $n$ extensions in $Ext(\mathbb{Z}/n,\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The torsion of $H_B^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is that of $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})=\pi_1(X)^{ab}$ (universal coefficient theorem for cohomology), so the simplest case should be a simply connected complex surface quotiented by a fixed point free holomorphic involution (or a prime order automorphism).

I would propose an [Enriques surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriques_surface), but I'm not at all convinced it is "simplest".

Comment: My answer crossed Donu's comments. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps evidence  that Enriques surfaces are the most
obvious examples, although perhaps not the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in a complex manifold which is not Kaehler? $\mathbb RP^3\times S^1$ admits a complex structure. Remove the origin from $\mathbb C^2$, and then divide by the free action of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2$ generated by $(x,y)\mapsto (2x,2y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$.

Comment: Thanks Tom, yes if you don't take the involution then this is the classical example of an Hopf surface! 